How can I set up my class in CSS so that text in a darkened section is not subjected to opacity?
I have a website with a video background in a header. There is text that sits on top of the video background. The white text against the video background can be difficult to read, so I set the opacity of the section where the video is to 0.4. The problem is that this also darkens the text, and I can't seem to stop it.
What I've tried: I have tried changing the z-index of the class where the text sits, but this did not work for me. I made sure that position was set to "relative," and they are. I am at a loss.
This is the HTML
   <section
    class="home-section bg-dark-30"
    id="home"
    data-background="assets/images/finance/finance_header_bg.png"
  >
    <div
      class="video-player"
      data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwWY-Zh-KLM', containment:'.home-section', startAt:30, mute:true, autoPlay:true, loop:true, opacity:1, showControls:true, showYTLogo:false}"
    ></div>
    <div class="video-controls-box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="video-controls">
          <a class="fa fa-volume-up" id="video-volume" href="#">&nbsp;</a
          ><a class="fa fa-pause" id="video-play" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titan-caption">
      <div class="caption-content">
        <div class="font-alt mb-30 titan-title-size-1">
          Hello &amp; welcome
        </div>
        <div class="header-text font-alt mb-40 titan-title-size-4">
          Clark Law, PLLC
        </div>
        <a class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-round" href="#about"
          >Learn More</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

Here is the CSS:
.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 2;
}

  

.titan-caption {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.titan-caption {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.caption-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

Here's a visual of the problem:
If it's helpful at all, the HTML and CSS are from ThemeWagon, located here:
LINK

opacity on the parent cannot be overriden by anything on the children. Move the opacity to the video

Thank you. In the code above, the opacity only seems to take effect if I apply it to the parents .home-section div. :(
